# How to return duplicate values from an array?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way that I could return duplicate values from an array in C#? also im looking to write a small algorithm that would return the most number of duplicate values in an array. for example

[1, 2,2,2 3,3] I need to return the duplicate values with the most number of occurrences and the number of occurrences as well.

I think I saw some post which said that It could be done using Linq but I have no clue what Linq is

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
IGrouping<int, int> mostOccurrences = data
    .GroupBy(value => value)
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
    .First();

Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} time(s).", mostOccurrences.Key, mostOccurrences.Count());
```

Note that if multiple values occur the same number of times (such as if you added another 3 to that list), the above code will only list one of them.  To handle that situation, try this:

```
int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
var occurrenceInfos = data
    .GroupBy(value => value)
    .Select(group =>
        new {
            Count = group.Count(),
            Value = group.Key
        }
    );
int maxOccurrenceCount = occurrenceInfos.Max(info => info.Count);
IEnumerable<int> maxOccurrenceValues = occurrenceInfos
    .Where(info => info.Count == maxOccurrenceCount)
    .Select(info => info.Value);

foreach (int value in maxOccurrenceValues)
    Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} time(s).", value, maxOccurrenceCount);
```

Comment: Hi this line seem to throw an invalid operations exception on this line var maxOccurrenceCount = occurrenceInfos.Max(info => info.Count);

Comment: Hi sorry it was my stupidity as the data array was empty! works like a charm, but I am confused how to return the values stored in maxOccurenceValues.

Comment: I updated my answer so the variables are declared with explicit types so it's a little clearer.  It really depends on what you want to use `maxOccurrenceValues` for, but since it's of type `IEnumerable<int>` you can use it as-is, or if you need an array call `maxOccurrenceValues.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this:

```
var data = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, };

var occurences =
    data
        .ToLookup(x => x)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var mostOccurences =
    occurences
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
        .First();
```

These will give you the following results:

[image: results]

Comment: Nice one, the only thing is that maybe you don't need the dictionary: `var occurences =
    from d in data.ToLookup(x => x)
    select new { d.Key, Count = d.Count() };`